# Sort an array of object based on an attribute in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to improve given algorithm of selecting a `Storage` box based on `Summary` info on the box. In order to retrieve the identifer (of summary object) which has the with the highest numItems attribute (of summary object), I would have to sort the `Summary[]`, an array of objects but I just can't figure how to sort by an attribute.

I found numerous examples of creating `ArrayList<Int> a = new ArrayList<Int>();` and then Using `Collections` to get maximum value but here, I am interested in other attribute and I just can't visualize how I would do that. Can you help?

```
public String selectNextDelivery(StorageBox.Summary[] summaries) throws NoBoxReadyException {
    if (summaries.length != 0) {
        for(StorageBox.Summary summary : summaries){
            if (summary.numItems > 0) {
                return summary.identifier;
            }
        }
    }
    // Otherwise no box is ready
    throw new NoBoxReadyException();
}
```

Comment: All you need to do is implement a Comparator interface. There already exists many ways to sort a collection of objects

Comment: Alternatively, you need to not immediately return an element from the list and instead look at all elements, then return the maximum

Comment: you could use `Comparable` interface by implementing it in your `Summary` class

Comment: @mojtab23 Oh, I accidentally left that part out - I did some search and I did come across implementing Comparable interface but by requirement of school assignment, I can't touch the Summary class. I have to deal with it here.

Comment: Why do you need to sort the entire array to find the max?

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, to get the maximum element in an array of objects using an attribute, use [`Stream#max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) with [`Comparator.comparingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)

```
return Stream.of(summaries)
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.numItems))
    .orElseThrow(() -> new NoBoxReadyException())
    .identifier;
```

Without Java 8, you can use [`Collections.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)) with a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
try {
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(summaries), new Comparator<StorageBox.Summary>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(StorageBox.Summary s1, StorageBox.Summary s2) {
            return Integer.compare(s1.numItems, s2.numItems);
        }
    }).identifier;
} catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
    throw new NoBoxReadyException();
}
```

Or you could implement it yourself with a standard `for` loop:

```
if (summaries.length == 0)
    throw new NoBoxReadyException();
StorageBox.Summary max = summaries[0];
for (int i = 1; i < summaries.length; i++)
    if (summaries[i].numItems > max.numItems)
        max = summaries[i];
return max.identifier;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Java 8 Streams you can do something like this:

```
Stream.of(summaries) //creating custom comparator which sorts based on identifier
    .sort(($1, $2) -> Integer.compare($1.identifier, $2.identifier))
    //Do something with your stream
```

If you want to get the first element from stream sorted by some attribute you can do:

```
 Stream.of(summaries)
     .max(Comparator.comparingInt(StorageBox.Summary::getIdentifier))
     .orElse(null);
```

Thanks 4castle for pointing out a Comparator.comparingInt() method

Comment: Using `sort` and `findFirst` together is overkill. It makes an O(n) operation into O(nlogn)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is using the `public static <T> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)` api, where it has the comparator with which to determine the maximum element. A null value indicates that the elements' natural ordering should be used.

Comment: You didn't mention, but this method is located in the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) class. It is very useful, though doesn't allow a custom exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comparators to sort-

```
Arrays.sort(summaries, new Comparator<Summary>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Summary o1, Summary o2) {

        return o1.numItems.compareTo(o2.numItems);
    }           
});
```

or Use the Collections api alongwith the Comparator to retrieve the max

```
Summary maxSummary = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(summaries), 
                                   new Comparator<Summary>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Summary o1, Summary o2) {

                return o1.numItems.compareTo(o2.numItems);
            }           
        });
```